# Combine physical drives and lose minimal files in case of failure

Tags: filesystems, lvm, raid

I need to store large files on a lot HDDs. I don't care losing data but I want to lose as few files as possible if/when a drive fails. As far as I understand, it's not possible to setup drives in raid 0 without stripping, or logical drives in LVM while chosing never to split files.

What would be the easiest way to setup that group of HDD in order to maximize utilization of space while minimizing the amount of large files lost if a drive fails?

Edit : so far I'm going with the solution of creating two volumes per physical drive ; one is full with files exclusive to that drive, and the other one is shared across many disks (up to 10) to use the last bit of space available ; i might switch to raid5 when I've figured the array upgrade/downgrade problem.

Comment: There can be no general answer I'm afraid and it will depend on your use case.

Comment: RAID0 is striping by definition - I don't get how this relates to LVM or anything else, if you don't want striping don't use RAID0. RAID5 comes to mind, but that's only going to work with at least 3 drives and you don't specify how many you got.

Comment: "I don't care losing data but I want to lose as few files as possible if/when a drive fails." Why?

Comment: @JeremyBoden because I have a backup somewhere else, i also want to use hundreds of small hdds to replicate in another location, the issue is that the drives are very small and the files mostly 80-120gb which would leave me with lots of empty space if they aren't combined somehow (eg. on 250gb drives)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov see the comment above for my use case

Comment: @Panki I do not want stripping so raid0 doesn't work, and i do not want to lose all my files if 1 drive fails so LVM won't work either. I have hundreds of small HDDs, would raid5 work and what's the overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Modern filesystems such as [OpenZFS](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Main_Page) or
[BTRFS](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/) might be able to possess the property you need. However, you are advised to make your own tests before relying on that property.